# Python crontab schedule job at certain hour

Tags: python, cron

I was reading python-crontab [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/python-crontab/) and I could not find a way to schedule a job every day at a certain hour. I want to have something like this:

```
0 17 * * * cd /root/myjob && /root/myjob/cron-run.sh # myJob
```

Which means to run the job every day at 17:00 PM, If I use this `job.every(17).hours()` it's gonna create `0 */17 * * *` which means (At every minute past every 17th hour) which is not exactly what I want and if I use `job.hour.on(17)` it's gonna create `* 17 * * *` which means (At every minute past hour 17). what I want to have is (`At 17:00`  => `0 17 * * *`)

```
from crontab import CronTab
cron = CronTab(user='root')
job = cron.new(command='cd /root/myjob && /root/myjob/cron-run.sh', comment='myJob')
#job.every(17).hours()
#job.hour.on(17)

for item in cron:
    print item

cron.write()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is `0 17 * * *`, which will run everyday at 17:00.

To achieve this you need to set the minute to 0:

```
job.hour.on(17)
job.minute.on(0)
```